# Change Sprite alpha previously changed by AlphaModifiers

Tags: android, andengine, alphablending, alpha-transparency

I'm running AlphaModifier on a Sprite

```
mSprite.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
mSprite.registerEntityModifier(new AlphaModifier(.5f,1,0.4f));
```

After that i want to cahnge alpha of mSprite to 1 again.  
i tried :

```
mSprite.setAlpha(1f);
```

It won't work

How can i set that alpha to 1 again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to bring the behaviour back from before you modified it, you should probably call

`setBlendFunction(IShape.BLENDFUNCTION_SOURCE_DEFAULT,  IShape.BLENDFUNCTION_DESTINATION_DEFAULT)`

otherwise before each rendering call it will use your parameters.
In addition, since the AlphaModifier will be called at each onUpdate() (this means at least one per frame), it will overwrite your new value. You should remove the modifier (or make sure that it is removed once it finishes), and then you can set the transparency you prefer.

Comment: I have preferred another way. your solution also worked so i'm accepting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay.

This is what I've done.

```
mSprite.setAlpha(0);
mSprite.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
mSprite.registerEntityModifier(new AlphaModifier(.5f,0,1));
```

After Alpha Modifier Finish i set the aplha to 0.
Then again register the blend function.
Then again register alphaModifier which brings alpha back to 1.

It gives a little animation kind of effect too so, I preferred this way.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I know there could be a better solution for this.